# remove the zombie process from the output of ps

Tags: linux, sed, grep, ps

I m not looking to kill a zombie process.

I m looking to avoid the display of zombie process in the `ps` command.

Are there an option to add to `ps` command inorder to avoid displaying the zombie process in the `ps` output. If not is it possible to do it with `grep` or `sed`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"ps" arguments might differ from implementation to implementation, but for some common ones:

```
ps auxwww | grep -v " Z "
```

or

```
ps -u <username> -o pid,stime,s,args | grep -v " Z "
```

Answer (score 1):

I like this one:

```
ps aux | awk '$8=="Z" { print $0 }'
```

Though you didn't mention `awk`...